# "has yet" means already happened or not?

Tags: word-meaning

> “They are asking you to put your life on the line and not paying you
>   —,  it's ridiculous,” said Donald Mihalek, 49, a 20-year Secret
>   Service veteran whose own retirement paperwork **has yet** to be processed
>   because of the shutdown.

I think here it means didn't happen.

By my colins bilingual dictionary

> No decision has yet been made.   尚未作出决定。

"No decision has yet" means didn't happen. So "decision has yet ..." should be means happened?

Comment: I'm having difficulty understanding your question, since both examples you give indicate that nothing has happened. If I interpret your last sentence correctly, are you actually asking if *X has yet to be Yd* is the opposite of ***no*** *X has yet to be Yd*?

Comment: “has yet to” == "has not done yet".

Comment: @dan, 其实我想问的是yet为什么被翻译成“已经”，但有时候却表示“尚未”。这不是矛盾的吗？我翻译不出来这句话，请英语好的@dan同学帮忙翻译翻译。

Comment: @Zhang "have yet to" or "be yet to" is a set phrase. You can search it in different dictionaries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> No decision has yet been made.

This means that it has not happened, but it might or will in the future. The word order is a little weird, though, as I would probably say, "No decision has been made yet."

> A decision has yet been made.

A native English-speaker would probably not say this. It just sounds too weird and confusing.

> A decision has yet to have been made.
>   A decision has not been made.
>   A decision has not been made yet.

Either of these sound a lot better than the second sentence and mean basically the same thing as "No decision has been made yet."

Answer (score 0):

according to Longman dictionary

**yet**

> You use yet in negative statements to indicate that **something has not**
>   **happened** up to the present time, although it probably will happen. You
>   can also use yet in questions to ask if **something has happened** up to
>   the present time. 尚 (用于否定句); 已经 (用于疑问句)

Yes, that it is. The dictionary explained it.